# Simple while loop repeats last value

Tags: c#, .net, loops, while-loop

Working on my .net foundations certification. On a practice test there is a question with some example code asking for the output. The correct answer is...
Loop 3
Loop 2
Loop 1
Loop 1

The problem is I don't understand why it's repeating that last "Loop 1". I put it into VS2015 and found that it is in fact correct. Note, I'm not asking for the code to be fixed, I'm asking for an explanation as to why it's repeating the last value. I've searched and am not finding a clear answer. So, here's the code.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
class Program
{
    private static int WriteToConsole(int NumWrites)
    {
        int i = NumWrites;
        while (i > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("loop {0}", i);
            i = WriteToConsole(i - 1);
        }
        return NumWrites - 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToConsole(3);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The best way for you to understand that is to set a breakpoint at `WriteToConsole(3);` in `Main()` and debug through it step by step.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please study about stack unwinding.

I will try to give you an idea.

- Calling order will be  WriteToConsole(3) then  WriteToConsole(2) then
  WriteToConsole(1) then WriteToConsole(0).
- WriteToConsole(0) will return -1 to WriteToConsole(1), so it wont go
  in while loop again.
- WriteToConsole(1) will return 0 to WriteToConsole(2), so it wont go
  in while loop again.
- WriteToConsole(2) will return 1 to WriteToConsole(3), so it will meet
  the condition (i > 0) and write to console.

Comment: Thank you Vivek. The note about studying stack unwinding was even more helpful than the explanation of this specific problem. That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example of the flow of the code.  Each indention represents a new stack (recursive call to `WriteToConsole`) and the `i` variables have been replaces with it's current value at that step in the code.

```
WriteToConsole(3)
    while(3>0)
    Console.WriteLine(3)
    WriteToConsole(2)
        while(2>0)
        Console.WriteLine(2)
        WriteToConsole(1)
            while(1>0)
            Console.WriteLine(1)
            WriteToConsole(0)
                while(0>0)
                return -1
            while(-1>0)
            return 0
        while(0>0)
        return 1
    while(1>0)
    Console.WriteLine(1)
    WriteToConsole(0)
        while(0>0)
        return -1
    while(-1>0)
    return 2
```

The recurisive calls to `WriteToConsole` basically write the current number and then decrements.  This will result in writing out 3 to 1.  But you can see that after the first set of recursive calls the local `i` variable will be set to 1 and you'll have one more pass through the `while` loop and thus it will print 1 a second time.  So for that reason giving it a starting number of 4 will result in an output of 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1. And passing in 5 would give 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that it is there is a recursive call inside a loop.
For the initial value of 3 the loop will execute for 3 times but due to the recursive call it will also start a new loop with initial value 2 that will execute once.

The higher the initial value the more the repetitions you'll find in the result

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how the recursive method is treating `i`. Each time `WriteToConsole` is called, it returns the nubmer it was given subtracted by 1. But when it is called inside the while loop, it is called with `i - 1`, so in effect the method is performing `i = i - 2;`. When each of the numbers are run with this pattern, you get the following behavior:

- `WriteToConsole(3);` executes twice: once for `3` and once for `1`.
- `WriteToConsole(2);` executes once for `2`, but not for `0`.
- `WriteToConsole(1);` executes once for `1`, but not for `-1`.
- `WriteToConsole(3);` only executes for `1` after the nested recursions have returned.

Which produces the following result:

```
loop 3
loop 2
loop 1
loop 1
```